# How to create output depending on words in a string

Tags: string, powershell, logic

say I have a script. The `$result = convertDoc(source, dest)` may have

> DAOpenDocument("c:\docs\test.xlsx") failed: no file is currently open (0x0010)

for a failure, or this for success:

> EX_CALLBACK_ID_PAGECOUNT: The File had 1 page.
>   Export successful: 1 output file(s) created.

I need to create a logic if $result has the keyword "failed" in the string then `Write-Host` failed else `$result` has the keyword "export successful" then Write-Host "successful"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$result | Select-String '(failed|export successful)' | % {
  if ($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value -eq 'failed') {
    Write-Host 'failed'
  } else {
    Write-Host 'successful'
  }
}
```

Note that `$_.Matches.Groups[1]` requires PowerShell v3. In earlier versions you have to expand the groups before you can access them:

```
$value = ($_.Matches | select -Expand Groups)[1].Value
```

That said, do you have control over `convertDoc()`? If so, it'd be a lot better to have that function throw an exception when no document is open and call it in a `try..catch` block:

```
try {
  $result = convertDoc(source, dest)
} catch {
  Write-host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code block. I will sure to try. It's not PS 3.0 so I will try the -expand groups. Also, I don't have any control over the source code for ConvertDoc, else I would put try/catch. I will let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching on $result. Options are -match, -contains, -like operators.
E.g. If ($result -match "failed") { write-host "failed"  } else {  write-host "mission sucess" }

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
$result = 'DAOpenDocument("c:\docs\test.xlsx") failed: no file is currently open  (0x0010)'

if($result.contains("failed"))
{ Write-Host "Failure" }
elseif($result.contains("successful"))
{write-host "Success!"}
else
{Write-Host "All is good"}
```